# intervention image gd library extension

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with Intervention\Image package. When I try to upload a book with no image file I get an error, **although I made a default image** in case the book has no cover so my book variable will always have an image file in its request

This problem only occurs on the production level, on my local testing Ubuntu VPS using VMware, it doesn't happen at all in the development level of laravel
Here's the log file showing the error
[Laravel log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzuk5.jpg)

I installed the GD library

```
GD support => enabled
GD headers=> 2.1.1
GD library version=>2.1.1
```

Comment: my github code [link](https://github.com/AhmedYMousa/SaraBookStore)

Comment: Would your image be accessible on non local environments? Is your path to it correct?

Comment: Out of scope here but you should remove the laravel readme from your github page, it makes no sense.

Comment: Check the save method:
`if($request->hasFile('book_cover'))
         {
            $image=$request->file('book_cover');
            $fileName=time() . '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
            $location=public_path('images/' .$fileName);
            Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);
            $book->image_path=$fileName;

         }`
To show the image in my view"
`<img  class="img-rounded " src="{{'images/'.$product->image_path}}">`
@Mihailo